# PHP matching an array value

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a little app to scrape css from a url. Demo it here: 
http://grahamthomas.me/temp/scrape/test/get-contents.php?url=http://www.grahamthomas.me

The script scrapes 1. the stylesheets and pulls the contents 2. inline style 3. stylesheets defined inline (i.e. @import)

The output you see is the contents of all the style found. And it's the output of 2 arrays. One is the selectors and one is the contents of the selector.

So the printed results are from a for loop, with this as the print statement:

```
echo $selectors[$i] . "{" . $sstyles[$i] . "}<br>";
```

To the point: I'm trying to input a div from the scraped page and then print out its style. I've tried using in_array and str_pos to search the selectors array for the one I'm interested in:

```
  if (strpos($pull, "#work") == true) {
    echo $pull . "<br>";
  }
```

I'm running into problems because of CSS syntax. The above loop works, but since #work can be referenced in other styles as a parent, it prints these 'children' also. Where I'm only interested in printing the #work style itself.

```
#body-container #work #thumb-hwy a {  }
#body-container #work #thumb-bjn a {  }
#body-container #work #thumb-wtfc a {  }
```

The solutions I've come up with are: 1. analyze the string and ensure there's nothing after the key I'm searching for (i.e. accept #work, but not #work #next). Or run the values through a REGEX which would search for the targeted key and ensure no other CSS style indicators followed, only the style itself.

Any help on how to do this, or improved logic ideas are appreciated!! I'm struggling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice solution I found while looking at a different question provides a great way to do a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which is basically what you'd be trying to do if you went with regex.

Try using this regex:

```
/(\#work)(?!\#[\b|\-]+$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure in you're regex that there's nothing after what you're searching for, its's first probably a good idea to trim the string of white-space. Then to make sure there's nothing before or after your search term use the begin and end characters `^` and `$`.
You should get something like this.
  `/^#work$/`

The problem with using a regex is the `.` as well as others are special characters.

I think you would be best off trying to use a real css parser like this : https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: Thanks for the response Greg. I actually have the CSS running through a parser, although I used CSSTidy (http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/). However, I couldn't quickly see how to pull out the value for a specific selector, when written in a nested format like #var #var #var .classiwant